# Javascript Convert String to Variable Recursive

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to make a game with html5 / canvas.

This is my first try, the idea is very basic.

We keep images in a ImageRepository as images object.

We don't want to manually set each image like `new Image()`.

```
var ImageRepository = new function() {
    var images = {
        background: "img/background.jpg",
        planets: {
            earth: "img/planets/earth.png",
            moon: "img/planets/moon.png"
        },
        ships: {
            fighter: "img/ships/fighter.png"
        },
        bullets: {
            fighter: {
                single: "img/bullets/fighter/single.png"
            }
        }
    }

    for(var i = 1; i <= images.length; i++) {

    }
}
```

The basic skeleton like this.

So, the question is;

How can i convert this object into `this.variable_name`?

For example:

```
this.background = newImage();
this.background.src = ourValueInImagesObject;
```

And how can we do this with multi-level object?

Comment: what is the point to have this data structure ? why not use a simple array to store all image url ? I would not use a loop to parse all this data structure as you initialize all your images for specific part of your game. Also urls seem useless since you can recreate them with the name of the objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would separate out the dataset.

```
var repo = {
    background: "img/background.jpg",
    planets: {
        earth: "img/planets/earth.png",
        moon: "img/planets/moon.png"
    },
    ships: {
        fighter: "img/ships/fighter.png"
    },
    bullets: {
        fighter: {
            single: "img/bullets/fighter/single.png"
        }
    }
}

function ImageRepository(repo) {

    // save a copy of this scope
    var _this = this;

    // use this recursive function to iterate over nested objects
    // it's an immediately invoked function into which the repo
    // object is passed. Note that this needs to be a named function.
    // Also note that the new function creates a new scope which is
    // why we needed to save the original scope to a new variable to use later
    var loop = function loop(obj) {

       // loop over the object
       for (var p in obj) {

            // if the 'node' is an object, pass the object
            // back to the recursive function
            if (typeof obj[p] === 'object') {
              loop(obj[p]);
            } else {

              // otherwise add the new images
              _this[p] = newImage();
              _this[p].src = obj[p];
            }
        }
    }(repo);
}
```

Create a new imageset by passing in your repo to the constructor:

```
var imageset = new ImageRepository(repo);
```

[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/37jauLz9/3/) shows the results with console logs instead of creating the actual images, but it should show you what's happening.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan, I've updated my code as there may be a scope issue with my original answer. This will fix it if there is.

Comment: A problem that will arise here is that you won't know if the images has loaded properly before attempting to use them. Image loading is async so you need to have a mechanism to deal with that as well (ie. onload).